# how do you run heroku client commands on travis-ci?

Tags: heroku, travis-ci

what can i add to my `.travis.yml` to run heroku client commands?

e.g. before deploy:

```
$ heroku maintenance:on
$ heroku pgbackups:capture --expire
```

and after deploy:

```
$ heroku maintenance:on
```

i've tried adding those commands to [`before_deploy`](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/heroku/#Running-commands-before-and-after-deploy) in `.travis.yml`, but it doesn't have access to the heroku cli tool.

bonus points if i can do this on the app level, e.g. do backups on the production branch, but not staging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just installed [Heroku toolbelt](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-command-line) in a build container. That's how it looks in my build:

```
sudo: required

before_script:
  # this install.sh script requires sudo
  - wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install.sh | sh

script:
  - /usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku restart --app my-heroku-app-name # requires HEROKU_API_KEY env variable
```

**Note**: installing Heroku requires sudo privilege (`sudo: required`) and if you have to access your app - `$HEROKU_API_KEY` environment variable must be set.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to everything you need with the [Heroku deployment support](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/heroku/) available on Travis CI.

If you need to do more, you need to [install Heroku toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/debian), and figure out how to do what you want.